# is it that easy working with ADO.NET Entity framework in real programming?

Tags: entity-framework

HI Guys,

I was watching  these videos series about Entity Framework:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff191186.aspx

is that easy building application in real world programming??? and is it ....reliable...has good performance...

"I am a graduate.."

thanks

Comment: Yes, it really is "that" easy. Although EF only gives you a data-model to work with, all the logic you'd have to add yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework is a valid real world data access tool.  It is very easy to get up and running with EF.  You simply import (or create in EF 4) your data model.  You then can rename it to make it more code friendly.  And then you are off querying databases.

**Performance**

I have been on multiple projects that use it, some which require high throughput, others that have low performance requirements.  Entity Framework out of the box is not the fastest solution in the world, so there are a lot of performance tweaks that have to go on, but its all do able.

**Reliability**

We never have issues with reliability.  We have never had an issue with EF in general, its always data content related.  Trying to insert duplicated data, etc.

**Other Tangibles**

EF follows a pattern which allows for you to do some fun stuff with templates and abstract classes.  All entities inerit from a class, entities that have references inherit from other classes.  All Entity Contexts inherit from ;) ObjectContext classes, which provide a base set of functionality that allows you to create generic DAO implementations that can be reused throughout the enterprise.

If you are using UI dev, you can also use Data Services that wrap EF, as a fast gateway to your databse.  The only downside of this is that you dont have access to the full suite of the Entity Framework.